# Manage data using switch/toggle button on html with php

Tags: php, html, database

I have one switch/toggle button that change the check status according to the data that i receive from databse.And if it's ON and if I click i want to save in a variable the value 0, and if i want to put ON i save 1.

The html code is this:

```
<div class="d5 col-md-2 col-xs-6">
        <?php if($ligado=='0'){
          ?><input id='cmn-toggle-1' class='cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round' onclick="$ligado=1"type='checkbox'unchecked >
        <label for='cmn-toggle-1'></label>
      <?php }
        else{
          ?>
          <input id='cmn-toggle-1' class='cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round' onclick="$ligado=0" type='checkbox'checked >
        <label for='cmn-toggle-1'></label>
        <?php
        }?>
      </div>
```

This is inside of a form and when i POST i want to send the variable with the right value. I dont know if with onClick works, because i tested and i get nothing.

In my php i have this:

```
    <?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
$descricao=$_GET['descricao'];

if(!empty($_POST['my_checkbox'])) {

$sql_query = "UPDATE alarme SET ligado=1 WHERE divisao=(SELECT id from    divisao where descricao = '$descricao');";
$result_set=mysqli_query($link, $sql_query);

} else {

$sql_query = "UPDATE alarme SET ligado=0 WHERE divisao=(SELECT id from divisao where descricao = '$descricao');";
$result_set=mysqli_query($link, $sql_query);

}
header("Location:verdispositivo.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use a php variable in Javascript.

Try this:

```
<input  id='cmn-toggle-1' 
        class='cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round'
        type='checkbox' 
        value='1'
        name='my_checkbox'
        <?php echo $ligado== '1' ? ' checked' : ''; ?> >
<label for='cmn-toggle-1'></label>
```

On submission you can check for the variable:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['my_checkbox'])) {

    // user checked the box

} else {

    // user did not check the box

}
```

Comment: If i change the Status of the button how do i save the value?and could u explain what that '?' is doing between 1 and checked?

Comment: @BrunoGonçalves Updated answer. The checkbox will not send '1' when the form is submitted and will send nothing then its unchecked.

Comment: so what variable i receive on the file that connects with database? For example i have to have this: $something=$_POSt['what i put here?'].

Comment: @BrunoGonçalves Updated answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one ...write update query in uppdatestatus.php file

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="<?=$row['id']?>"  name="onoffswitch" value="<?=$row['status']?>" class="js-switch" <?=$row['status'] == '1' ? 'checked' : '' ;?>/> 

$('input[name=onoffswitch]').click(function(){
var id=$(this).attr('id');
var status = $(this).val();
if(status == 1) {
    status = 0; 
} else {
    status = 1; 
}
//alert(id);
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'updateustaus.php',
        data:'id= ' + id + '&status='+status
    });
});
```